# Why doesn't the client application simply receive an access token directly and save the token exchange in OAuth?

Tags: oauth

An Authorization Code Flow for OAuth looks like the following:

[image]

I have omitted the flow with the API, as this is irrelevant to my question.

In OAuth, the user receives an access code from the authorization server in step (4) and passes it on to the client application (5) via redirection. In next steps (6 and 7), the client application exchanges this access code for an access token with the authentication server. That flow looks superfluous to me. **Why doesn't the client application simply receive an access token directly and save the token exchange?**

That flow would be easier:

[image]

I have made investigations against my question and often the answer is, that it is more secure with the token exchange, because the token doesn´t flow through the browser thus the token is more hidden and cannot be stolen. But that is not an argument for me, because the access code will also flow through the browser (look at my first diagram) and an attacker can steal the access code to get the access token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is when you pass an access token in the public application which is the browser in this case, the access token can easily be obtained by an attacker which can mimic the signed in user on your application.

The idea is the pass the code in the public domain, so the attacker can't obtain an access token without knowing the client secret. Access tokens should be kept very safe which is not somewhere in a browser.

In general the access token is kept server side so the attacker can't directly obtain it. Normally the user session (server side) will keep track of this access token, not meaning that the access token should be stored in the session.